# SCSCategory renamed to Category in Swift version of the mobileSDK generates error

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, lightning-knowledge, snap-ins, categories

I am using the Salesforce iOS mobileSDK to access Knowledge on Lightning Salesforce.

The data type of the categories thus generated is an array of SCSCategoryGroup objects. When you drill down the childCategories on each object, you get an array of SCSCategory objects.

SCSCategory is renamed to 'Category' in Swift version of the library. This now causes an compile error:
[image]

```
'Category' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context.
```

Has anyone else faced this? How do i get past this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from the mobileSDK dev team:
https://github.com/forcedotcom/ServiceSDK-iOS/issues/102

Since there is an overlap in the class names used by the ServiceSDK and the iOS core libraries, it identifies "Category" as being ambiguos.

In order to resolve this ambiguity, we need to mention the module name also.
In this case,

```
ServiceKnowledge.Category
```

Hope it helps!